# Can I use (mis-use) the globals() namespace for persistent storage?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm writing some utilities that I want to call as functions. They are called with a context which tends not to change, and some data. There is a lot of time consuming fooing to be done with the context, but once that is done, baring the data with it is fairly lightweight.

This will obviously map well onto the following pattern

```
class MyFunc():
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.foo_d_context=foo(context)
    def __call__(self, data):
        return bar(self.foo_d_context, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_callable=MyFunc(my_context)

    results1=my_callable(my_data1)
    results2=my_callable(my_data2)
```

However, my users are objecting to the initial creation of the my_callable object. What would be more acceptable to them is a function that can be used like ...

results=my_func(my_context, my_data)

... and have the function my_func see if the presistent data from a previous call exists, and is the same as the last call.

The problem with this is the first time the function is called, where can it store the persistent data? It seems that several utilities already in the Python standard libraries say they work like this, and the documentation talks about helper functions that set up the object. But I've not figured out how that works.

I can think of a way of doing it, but it feels wrong and unpythonic. It appears that I can put objects into the globals() namespace directly, and do so from within any function. So I could do

```
def my_func(context,data):
    glob=globals()
    try:
        if glob['__my_persistent_reference_context_$$$'] == context:
            return bar(glob['__my_foo_d_context_$$$'],data)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    glob['__my_foo_d_context_$$$']=foo(context)
    glob['__my_persistent_reference_context_$$$'] = context
    return bar(glob['__my_foo_d_context_$$$'],data)
```

Having written the above, it occurs to me that this function could create an object of the MyFunc class, which sounds closer to the concept I'm looking for, but it's still got to call it something, to put it somewhere, so that doesn't solve the basic 'can I use the globals namespace?' issue.

Is this OK?

Will it always work? (I'm using 2.6.6, will it still work eventually in 3?)

Is there a better way of doing it?

Is there a better namespace to pollute?

Should I just insist that the class way of doing it is simply the right way?

Comment: I think you're misusing the term "persistent"; it's almost never used to refer to something in memory.

Comment: Also, readability is important - I have not grepped quite what you want to do yet, I'm sure there is probably a better way than either method, but the second example is an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are saying, I think what you want to do is cache a value. This can be done pretty easily by using function attributes, which are not intrusive to other namespaces.

```
def my_func(context, data):
    try:
        reference, saved = my_func.cache
    except AttributeError:
        reference, saved = None, None
    computed = saved if reference == context else foo(context)
    my_func.cache = context, computed
    return bar(computed, data)
```

Comment: Function attributes - where did they spring from? I must learn to RTFM more effectively, but it's so damned big. I was working under the misapprehension that everything about a function evaporated when the function exited, so you needed to attach permanent (persistent) (ie not evaporating) storage to an object or a namespace. However I am now reminded that the function itself is an object, present in the module namespace that was imported, so that use of attributes makes perfect sense. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can put anything in `globals()` and if you use characters in the key that make it invalid as an identifier, it won't be accessible in the "normal" way. But let's take this step by step. If you're going to use a dictionary, why not just use *your own?*  You don't even need to declare it global in any functions that use it.

```
_my_global_state = {}

def foo(x):
    _my_global_state.setdefault("counter", 0)
    _my_global_state["counter"] += x
```

And so on.

But attribute syntax is nicer, so let's use an object instance:

```
_my_global_state = object()

def foo(x):
    if hasattr(_my_global_state, "counter"):
        _my_global_state.counter += x
    else:
        _my_global_state.counter = x
```

Of course, having made that leap, now you might as well put the data and the function together into a single... thingy. This is the real solution. Use classes to hold your data and the functions that operate on it.